# code vb6.0 Recognize identifier contain letters and digits

Tags: compiler-construction, vb6

i am trying  design simple compiler( scanner) and i need to know how i can write code Recognize identifier contain letters and digits  for example id45 and print that

Comment: You need to show us some code that we can comment on.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing exactly what you want if you want to check if a character string begins with letters and after that may contain letters or numbers you can use regular expressons

```
Function IsVar(txt as string) as Boolean
  'txt ="id45"

IsVar = False

Dim re1 As String
re1 ="((?:[a-z][a-z0-9_]*))"

Dim r As New RegExp
  r.Pattern = re1
  r.IgnoreCase = True

  bX = re.Test(sSendLine)
  If bX = True Then
IsVar = True
  End If

End Function
```

Basically the regular instruction "says"

```
[a-z] match a single character present in the list
   a-z a single character in the range between a and z (case sensitive)
[a-z0-9_]* match a single character present in the list
   a-z a single character in the range between a and z (case sensitive)
   0-9 or a single character in the range between 0 and 9
   _   or the character _ (underscore)
* do the previous match from zero to unlimited times (as many times as possible) [greedy]
```

if we should have a string "id45".

```
the first character is an I -- first instruction successful (next)
character 2 = d             -- second instruction successful (repeat)
character 3 = 4             -- second instruction successful (repeat)
character 4 = 5             -- second instruction successful (repeat)
no more characters          -- return true
```

If you do not want and underscore, simply take out the underscore in the regular expression.

Hope this helps
Charlie